# AngularJS Directive Remove ngClick attr and event listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, directive

I'm having an issue where in some situations I need to remove the ng-click="" attribute completely from an element depending on a few scenarios. I'm struggling to figure out how to remove the event listener after I remove the ngClick attribute. Even though the ngClick is removed, the event listener is still on that element and executes the ng-click regardless if it isn't even there.

I'm removing the ngClick attribute in a "link" AngularJS directive. Any idea what I should do?

Comment: You should use `data-ng-if` in that case. Read more about it :-)

Comment: you can write an expression in ng-click so do something like i.e. `ng-click="isClickEnabled ? doSomething() : null"` or write it into the `doSomething()` fn. As far as I know you can just remove ng-click...not easily anyway

Answer (score 2):

You could maintain one flag `isClickEnabled` that will say that the `ng-click` is enabled or disabled.

```
ng-click="isClickEnabled && callMyMethod()"
```

Comment: I would like to explore other options since it would break the application if we ever removed this feature/directive we are adding. Hence it is important that we manipulate ngClick in a directive, and not by adding extra variables to the value.